# Tracking website using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm about to publish my first website and wanted to track it using `Google Analytics`. What I want to know is if it is enough to add the tracking script of `Google Analytics` to my `index.html` or should I add this script to all my pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that you add the GA snippet script on each html page you want to track. The next decision is whether to place it in the head tag or before the closing body tag.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en